# I want to play with two mods in minecraft. One of them need a different version of minecraft forge than the other. How do I play with both?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-forge

One is the Furniture Mod which requires Minecraft Forge version 1.8.

The other is the Still Hungry Mod which requires Minecraft Forge version 1.7.

Comment: If they are incompatible, you probably can't use them. Are you sure it requires 1.7, or does it just require at least 1.7?

Comment: It said it required at least 1.7. What does that mean? (I'm not the smartest. Don't judge!) @Dragonrage

Comment: If it says at least 1.7, it should in theory work with 1.8

Comment: I will try it. @KazWolfe

Answer (score 1):

You can't, 1.8 is a major update. You have to find mods with same major versions.

E.g.: 1.8 - 1.7 Not good

1.8 - 1.8.2 good

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible. You can try to find Furniture mod for 1.7.

Comment: Why is this not possible?

Answer (score 0):

No. You need the same version of forge of the mod so you can play them or maybe if you have another computer you can name your computer the version name!

Answer (score 0):

The Minecraft Forge version you're using needs to be the same version as the mods you use. For instance, if using Minecraft forge 1.14.4 both of mods used need to also be version 1.14.4.